# Why I can't use res of type NextResponse in my api route?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a dynamic API route file for the POST request. Here is the code of that file:

```typescript
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import User from "@/models/User";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
    const data = await req.json();
    const { name, email, password, country } = data;
    await dbConnect();

    try {
        const user = await User.create({
            name, email, password, country
        })
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: true,
            data: user,
        }, {
            status: 201,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
        }, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
}
```

If I try to replace `NextResponse` inside the route with `res`, it gives me an error. Here's what I mean:

```
return res.json({
            success: true,
            data: user,
        }, {
            status: 201,
        })
```

Here's the error that it's giving me: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)` .

[image: Error screenshot]

Why I can't replace `NextResponse` with `res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `res` for your use-case, you can use:

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    ...

    try {
        return res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: user,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false })
    }
}
```

Do note that `res` must be of type `NextApiResponse` and not `NextResponse`.

Comment: In that case, should I use `NextApiRequest`?

Comment: If I use `NextApiRequest`, then it gives a ts error `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'NextApiRequest'.`. Also, if I use `NextApiResponse`, then it gives a ts error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.`

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more clearer.

Comment: It worked! What about `req`? It gives a ts error `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'NextApiRequest'.`

Comment: If I have it as `export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {` there seems to be no problem. But is okay to do it like this? Because I import them from different places: `import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";`

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to use like that.

Comment: Yes, I just did it. Thanks a lot! Last question: which way would you prefer? The original or the way you posted in your answer? And why?

Comment: Either way is fine. Personally I prefer the `res` way, since thats the same used in express, and its easier to read.

Comment: For some reason, it started giving me Error 500. I will have to return to the old way

Comment: @in43sh that's because you cannot use `res: NextResponse`. See the other answer. Hi Robin, sorry, but your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have that `export async function POST`, you are most likely using the new [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory), and there, an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) gets passed as parameter only the `request`.

To send a response back, you have to return a `Response` or use `NextResponse` from `next/server`, for example:

```typescript
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" });
  
  // OR

  return Response("Some plain text data")
}
```

The `res` of type `NextApiResponse` goes with `req` of type `NextApiRequest`, but they are for [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes) in the initial [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory).